# Upper bound for $\frac{x^{2k+2}}{1-x^2} $

Tags: calculus

My book says that if $x \in (-0.5, 0.5)$, then

$$\frac{x^{2k+2}}{1-x^2} \leq \frac{1}{3\cdot 4^k}$$

I don't understand how to get such upper bound?

Take $k=0 \Rightarrow \frac{x^{2}}{1-x^2} \leq \frac{0.25}{0.75} = \frac{1}{3}$

But how to figure out the general form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $|x| < .5 = \frac 1 2$, then

$$\frac{x^{2k + 2}}{1 - x^2} = \frac{x^2}{1 - x^2} \cdot (x^2)^k \le \frac 1 3 (x^2)^k \le \frac 1 3 \cdot \left(\frac 1 4\right)^k$$

using your previous estimate.

Comment: Wow! It's easier than it seems! Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome.